# Dictionary to Set

Tags: swift, dictionary, set

I've been trying to create a `Set` from a `[[Header: String]]` but haven't managed to do so yet.

I've tried using `map(_:)` and `flatMap(_:)` and `Set` but whenever I use `Set` it says:

> Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred.

How can I get the unique records in an array?

```
enum Header: String, CustomStringConvertible {

    case name  = "name"
    case info  = "info"

    var description: String { return rawValue }
}


let dict: [[Header: String]] = [
    [.name: "John", .info: "100"],
    [.name: "Mary", .info: "120"],
    [.name: "Mark", .info: "100"],
    [.name: "Lisa", .info: "120"],
    [.name: "John", .info: "140"],
    [.name: "Mark", .info: "140"],
    [.name: "Lisa", .info: "100"],
    [.name: "Mary", .info: "140"],
    [.name: "Mark", .info: "140"],
    [.name: "Mary", .info: "120"]
]
```

Comment: You would be much better off defining a `struct` with a `name` and `info` property then having an array of those `structs`. Make the `struct` hashable so you can put them in a Set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `Array` of Dictionaries. `Dictionary` does not conform to `Hashable`, so it can't be a member of a set, or a key within another `Dictionary`.

Using `enum`+`Dictionary` is simply not appropraite for the data you're trying to model. Instead, use a struct:

```
struct Person: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let info: Int // TODO: Give me a better name
}

let people = [
    Person(name: "John", info: 100),
    Person(name: "Mary", info: 120),
    Person(name: "Mark", info: 100),
    Person(name: "Lisa", info: 120),
    Person(name: "John", info: 140),
    Person(name: "Mark", info: 140),
    Person(name: "Lisa", info: 100),
    Person(name: "Mary", info: 140),
    Person(name: "Mark", info: 140),
    Person(name: "Mary", info: 120),
]

let uniquePeople = Set(people)
```